# OpenSSL CVE-2014-3508 - what can be read?

Tags: openssl

Per the OpenSSL announcement for [CVE-2014-3508](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-3508), sensitive information can be read from the stack.

> The OBJ_obj2txt function in crypto/objects/obj_dat.c in OpenSSL 0.9.8 before 0.9.8zb, 1.0.0 before 1.0.0n, and 1.0.1 before 1.0.1i, when pretty printing is used, does not ensure the presence of '\0' characters, which allows context-dependent attackers to obtain sensitive information from process stack memory by reading output from X509_name_oneline, X509_name_print_ex, and unspecified other functions.

Nothing I have found seems to have any further information.

What sensitive information can be read?  With heartbleed, the private key could (eventually) be read.  Can the private key be read with the pretty print function overflows?  What other sensitive information ahs been confirmed?

Comment: With heart bleed a private key *happen* to be read.  This is stack memory bug so if the private key is sitting on the stack somewhere then yes it could be read.  It depends on where the sensitive information is on the stack, and how much data can be read with the vulnerability.

Comment: @raz: Thanks :)  I'm hoping someone who knows more about the particular vulnerability will be able to provide those details.  For example, if the stack is guaranteed to always have a null within 30 bytes of known stack variables... or anything else that might make the risk clearer :)  Right now, it's pretty vague, making steps to recover vague.  It *could* require replacing private keys, or it *could* be unimportant, but this is very hard to tell without a good reference or reading the source (and I don't have the time to check the source, myself)